# Does paperclip need FFMPEG to upload videos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg

I'm using [this](https://github.com/ruby-av/paperclip-av-transcoder) gem right now:

Do i need to install `FFMPEG` like i did for uploading images (imagemagick)?

If I do, i can't seem to figure out how to install `FFMPEG` since I'm using `Nitrous.io`, which is a cloud based IDE.

I found out how to install Image magick from a line of code on `nitrous.io`, but i see nothing for `FFMPEG`.

So far I have tried googling quite a lot for an alternative encoder that's compatible with nitrous.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the system you are running and the configuration you need. if on MacOS i suggest using Homebrew.

https://ffmpeg.org/download.html